# Performance optimization of waveform drawing

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, drawing, core-graphics

I'm building an app that draw the waveform of input audio data.

Here is a visual representation of how it looks:

[image]

It behaves in similar way to Apple's native VoiceMemos app. But it lacks the performance. Waveform itself is a `UIScrollView` subclass where I draw instances of `CALayer` to represent purple 'bars' and add them as a sublayers. At the beginning waveform is empty, when sound input starts I update waveform with this function:

```
class ScrollingWaveformPlot: UIScrollView {

  var offset: CGFloat = 0
  var normalColor: UIColor?
  var waveforms: [CALayer] = []
  var lastBarRect: CGRect?
  var kBarWidth: Int = 5

  func updateGraph(with value: Float) {

    //Create instance
    self.lastBarRect = CGRect(x: self.offset,
                              y:   self.frame.height / 2,
                              width: CGFloat(self.barWidth),
                              height: -(CGFloat)(value * 2))


    let barLayer = CALayer()
    barLayer.bounds = self.lastBarRect!
    barLayer.position = CGPoint(x: self.offset + CGFloat(self.barWidth) / 2,
                                y: self.frame.height / 2)
    barLayer.backgroundColor = self.normalColor?.cgColor

    self.layer.addSublayer(barLayer)
    self.waveforms.append(barLayer)

    self.offset += 7

  }

...

}
```

When last rect of purple bar reaches the middle of screen I begin to increase `contentOffset.x` of waveform to keep it running like Apple's VoiceMemos app.

**The problem is:** when bar count reaches ~500...1000 some noticeable lag of waveform begin to happen during `setContentOffset`.

`self.inputAudioPlot.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: CGFloat(self.offset) - CGFloat(self.view.frame.width / 2 - 7),y: 0), animated: false)`

What can be optimized here? Any help appreciated.

Comment: you are adding subviews _ad infinitum_? If so, you need to implement this using `UICollectionView` so your views are reused

Comment: Did you found any solution?

Comment: @KD4 Hey! It was some time ago, but I came with a performant solution. I've made a cocoapod with an implementation - https://github.com/alexey-savchenko/ASWaveformPlayerView

Comment: @AlexeySavchenko Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3):

Simply remove the bars that get scrolled off-screen from their superlayer. If you want to get fancy you could put them in a queue to reuse when adding new samples, but this might not be worth the effort.

If you don’t let the user scroll inside that view it might even be worth it to not use a scroll view at all and instead move the visible bars to the left when you add a new one.

Of course if you do need to let the user scroll you have some more work to do. Then you first have to store all values you are displaying somewhere so you can get them back. With this you can override `layoutSubviews` to add all missing bars during scrolling.

This is basically how `UITableView` and `UICollectionView` works, so you might be able to implement this using a collection view and a custom layout. Doing it manually though might be easier and also perform a little better as well.

Comment: Thank you for an answer. Do you have any viable source on how to add views during scrolling and overriding 'layoutSubviews'? It a kind of mystery for me.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this will probably be a larger refactoring than you can afford but SpriteKit would probably give you better performance and control over rendering of the waveform.

You can use SpiteNodes (which are much faster than shape nodes) for the wave bars. You can implement scrolling by merely moving a parent node that contains all these sprites.

Spritekit is quite good at skipping non visible node when rendering and you can even dynamically remove/add node from the scene if the number of nodes becomes a problem.